# GetLayoutObjectAttribute("webviewer" ; "Content") doesn't reflect Javascript DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, dom, filemaker

I'm trying to use TinyMce in a webviewer in FileMaker but save the resulting HTML into a database field.

I am aware of the standard practice of using an fmp:// link with a script & parameter, but that won't work in Windows (the html content returned as the parameter will likely exceed the 2048 character limit).

I am using a javascript function to change the HTML DOM, putting the contents of the TinyMCE editor into another div on the page. However, when I use `GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "webviewer" ; "Content" )` it shows the content of the unmodified (pre-javascript altered) page, not the page after javascript has modified the DOM.

Sample file: http://cris.lc/sxti2

Is this expected behavior? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior on FileMaker Pro and FileMaker WebDirect.

FileMaker Go is different. `GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "webviewer" ; "Content" )` DOES get the current DOM with FileMaker Go.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful to know. Any suggestions on other methods I might try?

Comment: if you are you are using FileMaker 13.v2 or later, you can use the fmp URL protocol to fire a script in Filemaker and pass it parameters.

https://www.geistinteractive.com/2014/04/02/filemaker-13-0v2-fixes-fmp-url-protocol/

http://blog.jsfmp.com/post/88307579211/responsive-web-viewer-layouts-fmp-url-javascript-demo

Comment: Thanks; as I mentioned in my original post, unfortunately the HTML contents are too long to use that method reliably in Windows (which has a 2048-character limit on URLs).

Comment: On windows you can use the clipboard to get around the 2048 char limit.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks for the advice. Is there a method you recommend, or anywhere in particular I should start?